# NAB 2011 - Who's going?

Tags: nab, 2011

I'm thinking about going. I went last year - was a lot of fun.

Who plans on going?

And possibly do an SSD meet-up?

Comment: I just booked my ticket!!! 

Answer (score 1):

I'll be here, Vegas is home. Would be fun to do a meet and greet.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could.  Vegas is awfully close to me, but it's not in the budget.

Do let me know if you end up in SLC, though.

Answer (score 1):

I 'm going! Lets organize a meetup!

Tasos/ Soundsnap.com owner, leading sound effects site

Comment: Just got my ticket yesterday... I'm going as well :-) You have a stand? I'll pop in and say hi. 

Answer (score 0):

Last minute, yes. But I just got myself a ticket! Will be there some time between the 11th and the 14th.

Would be awesome to meet up.

Hurray!